# How to insert csv files in mysql db through multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, multiprocessing

```
import pymysql
import time
import csv,os
from multiprocessing import Pool

start = time.time()
db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="root",db="dummydb")
mycursor = db.cursor()
```

Here I am taking the input `csv` file:

```
csv_file = raw_input("Please enter absolute path for the input File (Just file name, to be precise), this script can process csv files only\n")

save_path = './'
input_csv = csv.reader(open(csv_file,'rU'), delimiter=",")
headers = input_csv.next()
for row in input_csv:
    validity_start = "2018-03-03 00:00:00"
    firstName = row[0]
    SMC = row[3]
    lastName = ""
    countrycode = "IN"
    validity_end = row[6]
    mobile = row[2]
    state = row[4] 
    city = row[5]

    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO dummydb.thirdparty_subscriber_o(first_name,last_name,country_code,validity_start_date,validity_end_date,mobile) VALUES ('"+str(firstName)+"','"+str(lastName)+"','"+str(countrycode)+"','"+str(validity_start)+"','"+str(validity_end)+"','"+str(mobile)+"')")
    db.commit()
    print "Inserted"

end = time.time()
print end-start
```

I want to implement multiprocessing Pool module to read and insert the file faster than usual.

Comment: You might want to consider using `threading` instead for this, since `multiprocessing` will introduce a lot of overhead just to do one db `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you csv contains N records. Read the csv and split the records population into M chunks of data each one of them has the size S.
Now you have M lists each one has the size S. Create a [process pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) and pass the lists to the pool. The '[func](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map)' is the function that does the INSERT into DB

Comment: The 'func' will have to connect to the database when it's called since each process runs in a separate memory-space — so it's unclear whether using `multiprocessing` will speed things up or not.